# Can somebody explain me following solidity code?

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, erc-20

I was going through fixed supply token 's solidity code from wiki and I have confusion regarding ApproveAndCallFallBack contract's receiveApproval functions, it is as under

// Token owner can approve for `spender` to transferFrom(...)   `tokens`
  // from the token owner's account. The `spender` contract function
  // `receiveApproval(...)` is then executed

```
 function approveAndCall(address spender, uint tokens, bytes data) public returns (bool success) {
    allowed[msg.sender][spender] = tokens;
    Approval(msg.sender, spender, tokens);
    ApproveAndCallFallBack(spender).receiveApproval(msg.sender, tokens, this, data);
    return true;
}
```

Understanding so far, this function is allowing spender contract to spend passed count of the token to be spent from msg.sender account, but I do not understand the use of the 3rd and 4th parameter in ApproveAndCallFallBack function.

This is some vague understanding can someone explain what is exactly going on here.

Here is the link source code of contract which contains  these functions

https://theethereum.wiki/w/index.php/ERC20_Token_Standard

Comment: Please ask one question at a time. Mixing two questions into one makes your question much less useful to future visitors. It also makes it harder to answer (because someone has to answer both questions at once).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spender contract needs to implement the `receiveApproval` function

```
function receiveApproval(
    address from, 
    uint256 _amount, 
    address _token, 
    bytes _data) public;
```

- The owner of the tokens is in the first parameter `from`
- The amount of tokens is in the second parameter `_amount`
- The token address is in the third parameter `_token`
- The last parameter `_data` is a custom data defined by the dapp, for example an referer address, or a customer id, or an operation code.

For example we can do this.

```
function receiveApproval(
    address from, 
    uint256 _amount, 
    address _token, 
    bytes _data) public {

    // Transfer tokens to spender
    ERC20(_token).transferFrom(from, this, _amount);

    // Raise an approved operation event
    // Frontend will show the purchase is complete
    bytes32 operationId = readOperationId(_data);
    emit ApprovedOperation(operationId);
}
```

Comment: Hi Understood your point. But i have one tiny doubt. In your sample code above code to transfer token from owner to spender should be ERC20(_token).transferFrom(from, this,_amount); instead of ERC20(_token).transferFrom(from, _amount);. Am i right?

Comment: @Prashank You are correct, it should be fixed now.

Comment: Thanxx man, for clearing all the doubts.

Answer (score 0):

Your understanding is correct. You will set a number of tokens and allow someone else to transfer the tokens as he/she wants, that is the approval. Then you will call a function on another contract, that is the call apart. There are only three parameters. The parameter "data" of type "bytes". This last parameter may be required by the contract that the function `approveAndCall` is calling. That function is `receiveApproval` and is defined in the interface in the contract that you are talking about. This basically describe that this function exist and is implemented in another contract.

I hope this help